# How can I pass a parameter from UI to server when using different navBarPage in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I open to different pages for similar functionality. I need to be able to invoke the same functionality but pass a parameter from ui.R to server.R based on which navBarPage the function is called from. Could you please let me know how to pass this parameter.

This is what I have

ui.R

```
navlistPanel(
widths = c(2, 10),
"Data", 
tabPanel("panel1", navbarPage("Tab1",
                             # Batsman tab
                             tabPanel("IPL batsman",
                                      h4('Analyze IPL batsman performances'),
                                      sidebarPanel(
                                        selectInput('batsmanFunc', 'Select function', batsmanFuncs),
                                        selectInput('batsman', 'Select batsman', IPLBatsmen,selectize=FALSE, size=20),
                                      ),
...
...))),
tabPanel("panel2",navbarPage("Tab2",
                                     # Batsman tab
                                     tabPanel("Intl T20 batsman",
                                              h4('Analyze Intl T20 batsman performances'),
                                              sidebarPanel(
                                                selectInput('batsmanFunc', 'Select function', batsmanFuncs),
                                                selectInput('batsman', 'Select batsman', T20MBatsmen,selectize=FALSE, size=20),  
                                              ),
  ...
  ))))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    
    # Analyze and display batsmen plots
    output$batsmanPlot <- renderPlot({  
        analyzeBatsmen(input$batsman,input$batsmanFunc)
```

I would like to pass an extra parameter to analyzeBatsmen() based on whether the call came from Tab1 or Tab2

Could you suggest how to do this?

Comment: First, you cannot have multiple elements with the same name, change them to have unique names

Comment: @PorkChop are you referring to the same function analyzeBatsmen? Why not? The idea is to reuse the function by passing another argument depending on from where the call came from. I already load different lists in the UI.I could create separate functions but that would be redundant code..

Comment: You have 2 sets of variables with the same names `batsmanFunc` and `batsman` those should give you an error

Comment: No errors so far. They are on 2 differenr navBarPages.

Comment: That should not report an error but this is wrong, the app should not work as expected if you do that. The fact that they are on different navbarPages does not matter. You have some identical ids in your app, and this is wrong.

Comment: @PorkChop, Stephane. Thanks. I stand corrected. I cannot have same ids. After changing the ids, I am now able to differentiate where the call came from and hence don't need to pass any parameter